# How to find the best combination beyond multiple JSON without generate all combination?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have many array of object. Each array have 5 object, and each array have objects with the same attribute `object_type`.

```
array_obj_type1 = [obj1_type1, obj2_type1, obj3_type1, obj4_type1, obj5_type1];
array_obj_type2 = [obj1_type2, obj2_type2, obj3_type2, obj4_type2, obj5_type2];
array_obj_type3 = [obj1_type3, obj2_type3, obj3_type3, obj4_type3, obj5_type3];
```

An object can be defined like this:

`obj1_type1 = { "obj_type":1, "strength": 10 }`

`obj2_type1 = { "obj_type":1, "strength": 20, "luck": 10 }`

I want to know the best combination with 3 slot `[type1,type2,type3]` each slot corresponding to one object type. If for example I search the best combination about the attribute `strength` I want to know a way to find the best combination without computing all other combination (because it's too heavy).

How can I do that ?

EDIT:
Tools like JMESPATH or jq don't interests me at all because I need something which doesn't use a specific library for node.js. I want to do it in pure js if it's possible.

Maybe using yield or iterator that delete the value that doesn't interest me can be a solution, because in fact I'm interested in the speed of this program. The faster the program is, the more interesting it is for me.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I don't start to code, but I already have function that calculate all combination from different array of object, but like I said I need the best result without generate all of this.